# running selenium commands with only chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, selenium, console, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know(if possible), while using selenium for testing UI, can the selenium commands be run via chrome console(developer console) similar to running/testing xpath for example like using `$x("//input[@name='inputname']")` which would give the input/tag with the specified name.

Here by selenium commands, i mean for example finding a text box and typing[type ( locator,value )] a text data(value) into it, using only the chrome console and not by running the test cases/scripts ?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to test selenium commands like filling up text boxes with text, clicking a button etc., directly from chrome console(similar to checking xpath via chrome console as mentioned earlier) instead of trying to run scripts or recording test cases.. something like $type('xpath/textboxname', 'texttobetyped') from chrome dev console would just fill the textbox with the text provided..

Answer (score 1):

Use the `innerText`, `wholeText`, or `value` properties. `$x` returns an array, so an index has to be specified. Here are some examples:

```
$x("//body")[0].innerText = 'hi'
$x("//input")[0].value = 'foo'
$x('//*[@id]')[3].firstChild.wholeText
```

**References**

- [DOM Level 3 Xpath: Interface XPathResult](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult)
- [MDN: text.wholeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/wholeText)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like
$x("//input[@name='inputname']").click